# Auth timeout problems with CakePHP

Tags: php, session, cakephp, timeout

This is really bugging me. Has been for years. No matter what I do with core.php or php.ini, my logins timeout after about an hour - usually. Some deployments of identical code and configuration timeout after a respectable amount of time.

This is what I have at the moment on one site - timed out after about an hour:

```
session.gc_divisor  1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  86400
session.gc_probability  1

Configure::write('Session.timeout', '28800');
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');
```

And another - lasted all night:

```
session.gc_divisor  100
session.gc_maxlifetime  14400
session.gc_probability  0

Configure::write('Session.timeout', '315360000');
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');
```

Now, before you get excited and say, "Well, the answer is there in the Session.timeout value", let me tell you that this site usually times out after about twenty minutes!

Comment: What lifetime value are your cookies getting set with? Is it a problem of the cookie expiring or the session getting garbage collected? (Check both with Firebug, whether cookies are being sent/retrieved in the Net tab.)

Comment: There are only two cookies being set: CAKEPHP & CakeCookie[lang].  They both have long lifetimes (2035 & 2011). I'm currently investigating the possibility that some image and css 404s might be tripping up the Auth.

Comment: Some new information on this: The session isn't being destroyed as if I try to load the page again - using the back button or re-entering the url - it loads fine without having to log in. Something hooky is happening inside my app or cake, I think.

Comment: Setting `session.gc_probability = 0` will mean cleanup will never happen, so sessions will last indefinitely (or until Cake itself decides they have expired).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere I read that on shared hosting, other applications can reset the session by clearing the php-defined session directory. This was alluded to by Rowlf in his answer.

CakePHP offers the option to configure the way sessions are handled. In `core.php` I changed this to `'cake'` (by default it is `'php'`):

```
/**
 * The preferred session handling method. Valid values:
 *
 * 'php'            Uses settings defined in your php.ini.
 * 'cake'       Saves session files in CakePHP's /tmp directory.
 * 'database'   Uses CakePHP's database sessions.
 */
Configure::write('Session.save', 'cake');
```

I also ensured that the session timeout and the corresponding php.ini values are the same:

```
/**
 * Session time out time (in seconds).
 * Actual value depends on 'Security.level' setting.
 */
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '86400');
```

So far, the system hasn't logged out.

Comment: Now, about a week later, it still seems to be working well. Colleagues also report that it now behaves as expected.

Comment: I tried the same thing but switching to session.save 'cake' results in a redirect loop 310 error. What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a Cake-specific thing; I've seen it when no frameworks were involved - it's most likely an issue with your PHP config settings.

Things you should check/do to fix the issue:

1. Specify a dedicated path to store
   sessions in `session.save_path` if you don't already do so.
   Don't store them in /tmp - some other process may come along and wipe them
   for you.
2. Make sure (and I mean *really* sure) that the value of `session.gc_maxlifetime` is what you think it is (86400 if you want your logins to time out after 24 hrs of inactivity, etc.). Same with `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_probability`. Even though the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) specifies that session settings can be set on any level, depending on the dodginess of your PHP build (they're all slightly buggy in their subtle ways :)) you may find they don't actually take effect unless set in the global php.ini file as opposed to in the code, .htaccess, etc. Just output them in your actual app to be sure they are applied.
3. Also, depending on your environment, check if the PHP CLI build is using the same php.ini file as the default PHP build - if the CLI build is using another config file and you have cron jobs using the CLI build, the cron job scripts could be invoking the session cleanup procedure.

Comment: 1. This is something I'll try - I've seen elsewhere that shared hosting can be a bit naughty like that.

2. The values in my original Q are output by phpinfo.

3. Presumably 1. would avoid this?

Comment: 2. phpinfo() gives you values applicable to the virtual host you're running - what about the actual app that's using Cake? Not likely, but something could be overwriting your php.ini settings.

3. No, it's a separate issue. Run `php --ini` on the command line and compare it with phpinfo() output to make the CLI version uses the same config file as the one you're modifying.

Comment: 2. I'm pretty sure nothing is overwriting the php.ini settings.
3. I don't have any cron jobs, but the CLI is using a different ini.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many CakePHP apps on the same server, this can be the cause of you troubles. Don't forget to :

1. Prefix each app differently ($prefix on core.php).
2. Change the name of each cookie path :

   ```
   Configure::write('Session', array(
   'defaults' => 'php',
   'timeout' => 4320,
   'ini' => array(
       'session.cookie_path' => '/name_app', // this for each app
   )));
   ```