# How to increase the session life time in cakephp?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am trying to increase the session lifetime in cakephp app. I have a `remember me` checkbox in login page. When checking the checkbox, I need to extend session time to 1 hour more to current time and any action inside the app after login  will need to extend session time to 1 hour more.

I have component file for login and all action will be entered in **startup function**.
I tried to extend the `session.cookie`(CakePHP's session cookie) lifetime, but it didn't works.

```
function startup(&$controller) {
  /* First try */
  setcookie(Configure::read('Session.cookie'),$_COOKIE[Configure::read('Session.cookie')], time() + 3600, "/"); // Configure::read('Session.cookie') is 'CAKEPHP'.
  /* Second try */
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
  /* Third try */
  session_set_cookie_params(time() + 3600);

  echo $this->Session->read('status').'   session  <br/>';
  echo $_SESSION['test'];
}
```

But all of these doesn't keep the session after `session.timeout`(CakePHP's session timeout) time. The session `status` and `test` varaibles are created on login. It will be retrieved until `session.timeout` is not reached.

I am using cakephp **v1.2**.

Comment: i think this can help u 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564217/auth-timeout-problems-with-cakephp

Comment: Tip: http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/02/more-persistent-sessions-in-cake2-x/#insight

Answer (score 0):

```
keep this in your core.php file 
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
            'timeout'  => 14400,  // 4 hours 
            'cookieTimeout' => 14400, // 4 hours 
            'cookie' => 'Your Cookie Name',
            )
        );
```

Comment: First of all this is syntax of Cakephp **v2.x** version. I have already tried with these changes in core with no success.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to keep very high session timeout. If your requirement is only to keep him logged for more time, then use some auto_login component like [www.milesj.me/resources/script/auto-login](http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/auto-login)